# C# Unit test fails on saving image to server but app works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I'm trying to save image from web url to my local ASP.Net project folder "~Content/Images"

Initially I was saving image like that:

```
imgUrl = "http://example.com/myimage.jpg";
imgName = Path.GetFileName(imgUrl);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + imgName));
```

But my unit test failed with `NullReferenceException` on `Server object` in `Server.MapPath()` method.

Then I tried another way to save the image.

```
imgUrl = "http://example.com/myimage.jpg";
imgName = Path.GetFileName(imgUrl);

byte[] data;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   data = client.DownloadData(imgUrl);

  if (data != null)
  {
   MemoryStream ioStream = new MemoryStream();
   ioStream = new MemoryStream(data);

    using (Stream originalBinaryDataStream = ioStream)
    {
     var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("~/Content/Images/" + imgName);
     Image image = Image.FromStream(originalBinaryDataStream);                                    
     image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);                                    
    }
  }
```

But unit test fails again. This time with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.` error.

By the way, the application works fine. This problem occurs only when I'm running unit tests.

Does anybody have ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your unit tests you will have to fake or Mock HttpContext.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online. 
example  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068851/Unit-testing-HttpContext-Current-outside-of-a-Cont

Answer (score 0):

> When either a Bitmap object or an Image object is constructed from a file, the file remains locked for the lifetime of the object. As a result, you cannot change an image and save it back to the same file where it originated. http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675

you can try this:

```
imgUrl = "http://example.com/myimage.jpg";
imgName = Path.GetFileName(imgUrl);

byte[] data;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    data = client.DownloadData(imgUrl);

if (data != null)
{
    using (MemoryStream ioStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("~/Content/Images/" + imgName);
        var fromStream = Image.FromStream(ioStream);
        Image image = new Bitmap(fromStream);
        fromStream.Dispose();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            image.Save(ioStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bytes = ioStream.ToArray();
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like it fixed NullReferenceError. But now I'm having another type of error, test method is trying to find specified folder in TestProject: - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\App\MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug\~\Content\Images\91n8pSBmhxL._SX480_.jpg'.

Comment: You should wrap `Path.Combine(...)` then you can mock it. After that, when you are mocking the method, you can set a valid path for saving the image.